# How to get the td value from a input:checked using jquery?

Tags: jquery

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to get the td data using `$(this)`.
Here's my attempt

```
<tbody id="testTable">
    <tr><td class="tdData"><input type="checkbox"></input></td></tr>
</tbody>

$("#testTable tr td > input:checked").each(function()
{
    alert($(this).parent().text()); // alert shows empty
    alert($(this).find(".tdData").text()); // alert shows empty
    alert(this.nodeName); // alert shows INPUT
    alert($(".tdData").text()); // alert shows data
});
```

Using `$(this)` does not seems to work.

Comment: There are no `<input>`s in your example.  Can you post a *real* example?

Comment: What data are you trying to get?  In your example the `<td>` is empty!

Comment: Your checkbox isn't checked, so your selector won't find anything.  Are you calling this in an `onchange` handler?

Comment: Is the `<input>` the only thing in the `tdData`?  If so, `.text()` won't show anything, since there is no text to show.  Try `.html()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this)` in an `each()` loop refers to the element posted in the initial statement, which is `$("#testTable tr td > input:checked")` ie the checkbox.

So if you like to get the td value of each cell just use

```
$("#testTable tr td").each(...
```

then `$(this)` refers to the table cell. Getting the text value of an input or an empty td won't return anything, as you seen.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#testTable tr td > input:checked").each(function()
{
     alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

Comment: alert display empty using this method... What could be the problem? No information from Firebug

Comment: Please post the full `testTable` html markup in your question. That would help!

Comment: Of course it's empty if you don't have any inputs in your markup.